# postfix + spamasassin on outgoing email

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

For domain **company.com**,

I have server with postfix + dovecot + spamassassin.

Currently spamassassin works just before dovecot:

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
```

This is because we want to get all spam messages and put it in spam folder.

This means all incoming mails to **something@company.com** are checked for spam.

However, each email of **company.com** have access to SMTP relay via their user and password (sasl auth via dovecot)

I want to check all these outgoing / relayed emails for spam as well, while server accepts all spam for local delivery for **company.com**.

Any ideas?